# Identifying last packet in a message sent by TCP

Tags: networking, tcp, packet

Say we have sender A sending a message to receiver B using TCP. Say the message to be sent from A to B is split into three packets of length 500 bytes, 500 bytes and 50 bytes, to be sent in that order. How does A indicate to B that the packet of length 50 bytes is the last part of the message? I can understand that an ACK from B to A, sent every other packet received by B, indicates using the sequence number how much data has been received by B since the last ACK was sent by B. I read that FIN is used to terminate the connection between the sender and receiver. However, I can't find a description of how the the last packet, of a message split into several packets, is indicated. I'm thinking the packets have to be reassembled, in order, before the message is sent to the receiving application. I think that as one of TCPs actions is to split the message into packets, there must be some way of the sender flagging the last packet of a message has been sent.

Comment: 'How does A indicate to B that the packet of length 50 bytes is the last part of the message?': It doesn't. There are no messages in TCP. It is a byte-stream. If you want message boundaries you have to use an application protocol that provides them, one way or the other.

Comment: @user207421 Is the following correct? The application sender, A, constructs complete messages such "GET.........", "PUSH ........", "OPEN ......". This whole message is in some buffer at A that gets "handed" to TCP. Now, TCP is designed to deliver byte-streams. So when a message is to be sent , TCP starts "eating" its way through the message from byte 0 up to some maximum packet size. If the message end has been reached or the maximum packet size reached, TCP at A sends that collection of bytes to receiver B. If there are more bytes to be sent from the application sender at A, TCP at end A ...

Comment: .. continues to send bytes from where it left off. At receiver B, TCP puts the received bytes into some buffer area that the application at B has prepared and the bytes from TCP packet or packets get put into that buffer at B. It is the application at B to "know" (from application protocol rules) what type and size of message to expect from A. When that receiving buffer at B is full, then (somehow) the application at B is signalled to read the message in its buffer (???) and process it.

Comment: TCP can send as little or as much as it likes in each segment, and it can delay sending to as to coalesce segments. That means that if you send X bytes and then Y bytes the receiver can receive anything from 1 to X+Y bytes in a single read.

Comment: Why have there been two votes to close this question? I misunderstood the behaviour of TCP and was asking for clarification - but isn't that the whole point of asking a question? @RonMaupin identified and corrected my misunderstanding, giving a clear answer. If my question was closed, Ron's answer would be lost to those seeking an answer to the same question - even if the question contained misunderstanding. Isn't a benefit of stack exchange for a repository of answers, generously written by volunteers, to address clearly-stated questions, even if the question is based on misunderstanding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think that as one of TCPs actions is to split the message into
> packets

No, TCP takes a stream of data and segments it into PDUs called *segments*. It is IP that uses the TCP *segments* as the payload of IP *packets*, which are in turn the payload of the data-link protocol, e.g. ethernet, *frames*.

> However, I can't find a description of how the the last packet, of a
> message split into several packets, is indicated.

Something like that is up to a higher protocol, e.g. HTTP. I think you are looking at TCP the wrong way. A TCP connection is like a bidirectional pipe; whatever you put in one end comes out the other end. TCP has no idea of the data structure, it just sends whatever it gets from the application or application-layer protocol. When an application or application-layer protocol is through using the connection, it tells TCP to tear it down.

The receiving TCP simply receives data and reorders it, asking for lost or missing segments. It passes properly ordered data up to the application or application-layer protocol, having no idea of the data structure because it is just a data stream to TCP.

Also, remember that both ends of a TCP connection are peers that can send and receive, and either end can send a segment with FIN that tells the other end that it is done sending, but the end sending the FIN is obligated to continue to receive until the other end also sends a FIN to say it is done sending. Either side could also kill the connection with a RST segment.

> there must be some way of the sender flagging the last packet of a
> message has been sent.

Probably, but that is not the job of TCP, that is up to the application or application-layer protocol. When the application-layer is done, it tells TCP to close, and that starts the FIN process. TCP has no idea what is the last part of a message is because it knows nothing about the data. It keeps the pipe open until it is told to close it.

Comment: A very clear and thorough answer .